# Probability of certain number of sequences in coin flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If a biased coin is flipped $10$ times, how can I calculate the probability of NOT having more than $5$ runs? A run or group is the maximal sequence of consecutive flips that are all the same. For instance HTTHHH has a total of three runs.

There is a similar thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259648/coin-toss-and-number-of-groups) but the offered solution is unclear.
Thanks

Comment: Can you calculate the complement? That is, can you calculate the probability of having more than $5$ runs?

Comment: Like The Count was saying, it's usually easier to find the compliment of an event occurring as opposed to finding the probability itself.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the compliment?

Comment: @TheCount It is actually easier to calculate the probability of the event than the complement, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$P(X=k)$ is the probability of $k$ groups.   For a fair coin, there are $2\binom {9} {k-1}$ outcomes in this event, among a sample space of $2^{10}$ equally probable outcomes.   Calculated by selecting $k-1$ from the $9$ 'spaces' between the flips where a change of group could happen.

Can you adjust this for a biased coin?

So you now can find $\mathsf P(X < 5)$